# Using iterator for printing cv::Mat content works only in single step debugging mode

Tags: opencv, vector, iterator, cout

I have the following class (only essential information is shown):

```
class ImageContainer
{
  private:
    //...
    cv::Mat content;
  public:
    //...
    cv::Mat getContent();
};
```

The getContent() does nothing but return a copy of the member content. I have tested it and it's working - cv::Mat::empty() returns *false* when I check the return value of getContent() and I also do some other calculations again using the returned value from this function.

For testing purposes I have created a vector

```
std::vector<ImageContainer> ics;
```

and filled it with a bunch of ImageContainer object. I want to print their **content** members calling **getContent()**. Note that OpenCV offers an overloaded **<<** for this purpose and I'm using it. Here comes the weird part:

1. If I use **at()** or **[]** in a loop over **ics** it prints everything just fine

   ```
   for(int ic = 0; ic < ics.size(); ++ic)
     std::cout << ics.at(ic).getContent() << std::endl;
   ```
2. If I use an iterator in a loop over **ics** I get nothing at all
   UNLESS I'm in step debugging mode and I've placed a breakpoint inside my loop.

   ```
   std::vector<ImageContainer>::iterator ic = ics.begin();
   for(; ic != ics.end(); ++ic)
     std::cout << *ic.getContent() << std::endl;
   ```

I have tried using a constant interator (shouldn't make any difference here whatsoever) and also "\n" instead of **std::endl** and flushed the **std::cout**-buffer after my loop has finished looping but the problem is still present. Problem is probably trivial but I really don't get it.

EDIT: As requested a small example (sorry I didn't post it earlier; the code is pretty complex and I though that the matter is quite trivial so no example would be needed). It represents the exact class structure that I'm having in my own code. I'm using a dummy 3x3 zero matrix. I forgot the exact headers needed since I have a whole bunch of these so not all are required:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

class ImageContainer
{
  private:
    cv::Mat content;
  public:
    ImageContainer();
    cv::Mat getContent();
};

ImageContainer::ImageContainer()
{
  content = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
}

cv::Mat ImageContainer::getContent()
{
  return content;
}

class ImageManager
{
  private:
    std::vector<ImageContainer> imageContainers;
  public:
    ImageManager();
    std::vector<ImageContainer> getImageContainers();
};

ImageManager::ImageManager()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    ImageContainer dummy;
    imageContainers.push_back(dummy);
  }
}

std::vector<ImageContainer> ImageManager::getImageContainers()
{
  return imageContainers;
}

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
  ImageManager IM;

  cout << "Using indexing:" << endl;
  for(int ic = 0; ic < IM.getImageContainers().size(); ++ic)
    cout << IMT.getImageContainers().at(ic).getContent() << endl;

  cout << "Using iterators:" << endl;

  std::vector<ImageContainer>::iterator ic = IM.getImageContainers().begin();
  for(; ic != IMT.getImageContainers().end(); ++ic)
    cout << (*ic).getContent() << endl;
}
```

In the first loop we get the output

```
[0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0]
```

but in the second

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you try to use `std::cout << ic->getContent() << std::endl;` instead of `std::cout << *ic.getContent() << std::endl;` ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the behaviour remains the same as previously described.

Comment: Can you make a minimum working example ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what compiler you're using, but with VS2010 your code crashes when reaching the beginning of the second loop.

The problem is due to your `ImageManager::getImageContainer()` function. In its current form, it returns a copy of the variable `imageContainers`, therefore your calls to `begin()` and `end()` return iterators from distinct vectors. If you use a different compiler, you might have a different behavior explaining why something gets printed but not what you expected.

Declaring `ImageManager::getImageContainers()` as follows solves the problem for me:

```
std::vector<ImageContainer>& ImageManager::getImageContainers()
```

The same goes for `ImageContainer::getContent()`, the function should return a `cv::Mat &`.